# Hosting for erlang application

Tags: erlang, hosting

Is there erlang hosting anywhere?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think that the best that you'll be able to do is to get a VPS where you can install Erlang.

There don't appear to be any dedicated Erlang hosting services.

Answer (score 29):

You can also use Heroku?
The build pack is here: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-erlang
And a sample app and configuration here: https://github.com/6/heroku-erlang-example

Hope this helps.

Comment: We also have an experimental R15B buildpack here: https://github.com/archaelus/heroku-buildpack-erlang . There are some restrictions - you have to be building an app that listens on an http port (unless you contact us and get a generic tcp port), and you can't yet build a clustered application. We're working on removing those restrictions, but they stand for now. You can still host a single-node yaws/webmachine/cowboy app with us easily however.

Comment: This is pretty much the answer I was looking for when I googled the same question as the OP.

Comment: I sadly cannot get it work, I know this thread is old, but do you get it work? :)

Answer (score 14):

You don't necessarily need to deploy Erlang on the target machine, what you can do is deploy your application as self-contained release (releases are an actual concept http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/release_structure.html). That means you build your application on a machine that has the Erlang version installed you want to use, e.g. your CI server, and generate a release of your application. The release brings the Erlang runtime (ERTS) and all libraries it needs from your build server with it (the build and target architecture should be the same) and when you use rebar even a startup script.

Basho's rebar tool simplified generating releases quite a bit (see https://github.com/basho/rebar). If you use rebar your application has to be OTP compliant (see link about releases).

One disadvantage of this approach is that your release, compared to your actual application, can be quite big. But you also can experiment with multiple versions of Erlang and don't need build tools for Erlang on the target machine.

---

Edit:

The future of hosting Erlang applications for high performance will most likely be:

[Erlang on Xen](http://erlangonxen.org/)

which runs Erlang on an hypervisor without operating system underneath.

Answer (score 13):

I usually rent EC2 instances and install erlang over there.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [cartridge available](https://github.com/thijsterlouw/openshift-erlang) for running Erlang  on  Redhat's [Openshift](http://openshift.com/) Paas which is such an easy way to host an app that it's sinful.

Answer (score 0):

VPS Hosting with XEN virtualization would be Best choice. Where you have complete access or control over OS kernel and comes with basic and required module setting. It will give you high performance, premium outcome, and more.

Answer (score -1):

Well today you can try [digital ocean](https://m.do.co/c/2436beab6df6). It has linux Ubuntu VM with huge possibilities. And it is stable and cheap solution. [About installing](https://www.howtodojo.com/2016/03/install-erlang-ubuntu-14-04/) `Erlang`. I think that today it is modern solution.